# Changing Knockout value bindings based on dynamic field visibility

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I set up a simple example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/YzKX9/5/

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.  Using KnockoutJS, I have a <span> tag bound to a computed observable using the text binding:

```
Full name: <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
```

When the form is loaded, the values come from a set of fields:

```
First Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /><br />
MI Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: middleInitial" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" />
```

However,  I have another set of fields that are hidden that have the same binding definitions and I control their visibility with a checkbox.  When those fields are visible, I'd like to have those fields control the text in the computed observable and remove the data-binding from the initial set of fields.

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. I thought maybe removing the *data-bind* attribute from the first set of fields would work but it didn't.  There's probably a much simpler way to go about this and I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to support accept/cancel then this might help.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

I used it with much success, the new values are only pushed to the observable if you accept the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach for what you are trying to do would likely be to add an observable to track whether you are doing a name change. You would bind that to your checkbox, control the visibility of the second set of fields, and use it in your computed. The code might look like:

```
function EmployeeViewModel(firstName, lastName, middleInitial){
    this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    this.middleInitial = ko.observable(middleInitial);

    this.newFirstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.newLastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    this.newMiddleInitial = ko.observable(middleInitial);

    this.isNameChange = ko.observable(false);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        if (this.isNameChange()) {
            return this.newLastName() + ", " + this.newFirstName() + " " + this.newMiddleInitial();    
        }

        return this.lastName() + ", " + this.firstName() + " " + this.middleInitial();
    }, this);
}
```

You would use the `checked` binding against the input and would not need to use jQuery to handle the change.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jb79U/

Comment: I like your answer because a) it's clean and simple and b) the jsfiddle link helps to see it in action.  I'll attempt to incorporate this in my code and see how it works. I appreciate your help (along with the other responses too, of course).

Comment: @beaudetious I think there's a problem in this answer ==>  RPNiemeyer is binding his "new" model variables to the **same** "original" form `INPUT`s, instead of the "new" form INPUTs.  I think that's a mistake... won't it be stuck with the original 3 inputs, regardless of whether checked or not?

Comment: @fd2g - the values are just initialized from the original supplied values. From that point on, they will have a life of their own and are bound separately to the inputs. When someone checks that it is a name change, the values will have been defaulted to the original values.

Comment: that's very a cool trick... beautiful answer either way... you are the Knockout god, after all :-)  Just wondering if that was the OP's desire to reset the value from the original each time it's clicked?... @beaudetious: was that what you wanted?  Or did you want the 2nd "new" set of `INPUT`s to remember their value/whatever you typed in them?

Comment: @fd2g - they are just initialized from the original values and not reset on each click of the checkbox.

Comment: @fd2g Initially I wasn't concerned about initializing the new name fields.  However, now that I've integrated this solution into my working app I am assigning values to those fields directly via code behind.  If there are no values to start with (since there's nothing in the database) then blank values work fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### **THIS WILL WORK PERFECTLY**:

---

```
                                                                                 .               
<div id="result">  
  Fullname: <span id="fullName" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
  <hr />
  <h3>
    Options
  </h3>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: chkNameChange" id="chkNameChange" />Name change?
  <hr />
  <div id="sectionOne">
    <h3 id="headerSectionOne">
      Name
    </h3>
    First Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" />
    <br />
    MI Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: middleInitial" />
    <br />
    Last Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div id="sectionTwo" style="display: none;">
    <h3>
      New Name
    </h3>
    First Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: firstNameNew" />
    <br />
    MI Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: middleInitialNew" />
    <br />
    Last Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: lastNameNew" />
  </div>
```

### Then your JavaScript:

```
function EmployeeViewModel(firstName, lastName, middleInitial, firstNameNew, lastNameNew, middleInitialNew) {
    var self = this;

    self.chkNameChange = ko.observable(false);

    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    self.middleInitial = ko.observable(middleInitial);

    self.firstNameNew = ko.observable(firstNameNew);
    self.lastNameNew = ko.observable(lastNameNew);
    self.middleInitialNew = ko.observable(middleInitialNew);

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!self.chkNameChange()){
            return self.lastName() + ", " + self.firstName() + " " + self.middleInitial();
        }
        else{
            return self.lastNameNew() + ", " + self.firstNameNew() + " " + self.middleInitialNew();
        }
    }, self);

}

var evm = new EmployeeViewModel("John", "Doe", "Q", "", "", "");
ko.applyBindings(evm);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chkNameChange").live("click", function (event) {
        if ($("#chkNameChange").is(':checked')) {
            $("#headerSectionOne").text("Former Name");
            $("#sectionTwo").show();
        } else {
            $("#headerSectionOne").text("Name");
            $("#sectionTwo").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks to be basically the same as the answer that I provided. You could also use your `chkNameChange` observable in the binding to do the Former Name/Name stuff too rather than needing to add the jQuery handler.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer yeah, handing in the computed() would be nice.  I think in your answer you bound your "new" model variables to the **same** "original" form `INPUT`s.  I think that's a mistake... won't it be stuck with the original 3 inputs, regardless of whether checked or not?

Comment: The variables were just both initialized from the original values. From then on, they will have a life of their own and are bound separately to the inputs.

Comment: that's very a cool trick... beautiful answer either way... you are the Knockout god, after all :-)  Just wondering if that was the OP's desire to reset the value from the original each time it's clicked?... @beaudetious: was that what you wanted?  Or did you want the 2nd "new" set of `INPUT`s to remember their value/whatever you typed in them?

Answer (score 0):

You can **clean**  the bindings for your div elements depending on your check box. **ko.cleanNode** method will remove the bindings from the DOM elements, and you can apply bindings again on the clean DOM nodes.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a5PAu/)**

```
function EmployeeViewModel(firstName, lastName, middleInitial){
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    self.middleInitial = ko.observable(middleInitial);

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.lastName() + ", " + self.firstName() + " " + self.middleInitial();
    }, self);
}

var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel("John", "Doe", "Q");
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#chkNameChange").live("click", function (event) {                
         if ($("#chkNameChange").is(':checked')) {
             $("#headerSectionOne").text("Former Name");
             $("#sectionTwo").show();
             ko.cleanNode($("#sectionOne")[0]);
             if (ko.dataFor($("#sectionTwo")[0])) {
                  ko.applyBindings(viewModel,$("#sectionTwo")[0]);
             }
         }
         else{
            $("#headerSectionOne").text("Name");
             $("#sectionTwo").hide();

             ko.cleanNode($("#sectionTwo")[0]);
             if (ko.dataFor($("#sectionOne")[0])) {
                  ko.applyBindings(viewModel,$("#sectionOne")[0]);
             }
         }
     });
});
```